# Set column values based on lookup from other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a **DataFrame** with **dates**, **categories**, and a column that shows if a one-off **event** has happened for that category. I want to create a new column with the **time until** the event happening, or some indicator there's no event, such as a negative time.

The dataset is quite big, and I'm imagining there's a better solution than brute-forcing this with loops that someone better with Pandas would know!

So, in short, if I create my dataset like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

#create example dataset
data = {'categories':['a','b','c']*4,'dates':[i for i in range(4) for j in range(3)],'event':[0]*3*4}

#add a couple of events
data['event'][4] = 1
data['event'][9] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How would I best arrive at output that looks like this?

```
   categories  dates  event  time_until
0           a      0      0           3
1           b      0      0           1
2           c      0      0          -1
3           a      1      0           2
4           b      1      1           0
5           c      1      0          -1
6           a      2      0           1
7           b      2      0          -1
8           c      2      0          -1
9           a      3      1           0
10          b      3      0          -1
11          c      3      0          -1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby`

```
def f(s):
    s = s.reset_index(drop=True)
    one = s[s.eq(1)]
    if one.empty: return -1
    return -s.index + one.index[0]
```

```
df.groupby('categories').event.transform(f)
```

---

```
  categories  dates  event  time_until
0           a      0      0           3
1           b      0      0           1
2           c      0      0          -1
3           a      1      0           2
4           b      1      1           0
5           c      1      0          -1
6           a      2      0           1
7           b      2      0          -1
8           c      2      0          -1
9           a      3      1           0
10          b      3      0          -2
11          c      3      0          -1
```

Notice that this finds the distance even after the event happened. So, for the following event, you get the following output

```
event = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
until = [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
```

If you need to perpetuate all negative values with `-1`, then just adjust at the end

```
df.time_until.where(df.time_until >= -1, -1)
```

Comment: Really nice solution, I wonder if mine could be refactored in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
df.sort_values(by=['categories', 'dates'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
df['tmp'] = df.groupby('categories')['event'].transform('cumsum')
df['time_until'] = df.groupby('categories')['tmp'].transform('cumsum') - 1
df.drop(columns='tmp', inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by=['dates', 'categories'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
      categories  dates  event  time_until
0           a      0      0           3
1           b      0      0           1
2           c      0      0          -1
3           a      1      0           2
4           b      1      1           0
5           c      1      0          -1
6           a      2      0           1
7           b      2      0          -1
8           c      2      0          -1
9           a      3      1           0
10          b      3      0          -1
11          c      3      0          -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'categories':['a','b','c']*4,
        'dates':[i for i in range(4) for j in range(3)],
        'event':[0, 1, 0]*4}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# One way
df.loc[df.event == 0, 'Newevents'] = 'Cancelled'
df.loc[df.event != 0, 'Newevents'] = 'Scheduled'

# Another way
conditions = [
    (df['categories'] == "a"),
    (df['categories'] == "b"),
    (df['categories'] == "c")]
choices = ['None', 'Completed', 'Scheduled']
df['NewCategories'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='black')
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
categories  dates  event
0           a      0      0
1           b      0      1
2           c      0      0
3           a      1      0
4           b      1      1
5           c      1      0
6           a      2      0
7           b      2      1
8           c      2      0
9           a      3      0
10          b      3      1
11          c      3      0
categories  dates  event  Newevents NewCategories
0           a      0      0  Cancelled          None
1           b      0      1  Scheduled     Completed
2           c      0      0  Cancelled     Scheduled
3           a      1      0  Cancelled          None
4           b      1      1  Scheduled     Completed
5           c      1      0  Cancelled     Scheduled
6           a      2      0  Cancelled          None
7           b      2      1  Scheduled     Completed
8           c      2      0  Cancelled     Scheduled
9           a      3      0  Cancelled          None
10          b      3      1  Scheduled     Completed
11          c      3      0  Cancelled
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's expected output?